# How can I refresh the jupyter nbextensions SETTINGS on an existing jupyter notebook? New notebooks take on the new settings, but old notebooks don't

Tags: python, json, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I use the `Table of Contents (2)` package from [jupyter nbextensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions). This package allows for a table of contents at the top of the document and/or a scalable table of contents panel on the left-hand-side, using the `#`/`##`/etc. lines in Markdown cells.

When I configure the extension to have the left-hand panel "off" and the header-table of contents "on" (using the GUI `Nbextensions` tab), **new notebooks take on the new settings, but old notebooks keep the old settings**. I've also verified that the **new options appear in the main json file** `.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json`.

How can I refresh old notebooks to these new `Nbextension` settings?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal solution, but apparently this can be done by editing the notebook-specific `.json` metadata. This is under the `Edit` tab, option `Edit Notebook Metadata` -- just change the fields manually to match whatever is in your default settings in `.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json`.

Ideally, of course, this should be automated. Hoping someone knows how.